# How to send Chrome notification with http to specific user

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications

I'm trying to send a broswer notification to a specific user with my app.
But I'm reading these documentations, and I don't find anywhere how to get a "browser id" of the user when he/she allows my app (I don't have https, only http) to send a notification, so I can send a notification sometime later.
I already read these documentations, and I didn't find a method to get this id and add to my database:

[Notifiy.js](http://http:/https://alxgbsn.co.uk/2013/02/20/notify-js-a-handy-wrapper-for-the-web-notifications-api/)

[W3C webnotifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/)

How can I do this?
I know it is possible because this site: http://espn.uol.com.br/ does it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to push a message from your server, you'll need to use some sort of event driven system that has support for clientside integration.

Something like [pusher](https://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-notifications) might give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to have a ready app like pusher in my app. I want to understand how the api works, so I can create my own pusher. Thanks anyway.

Comment: hm, I didn't understand how socketo.me can help. The notification doesn't need to be on real time. I just want to know how to get a browser id from someone and send then a push later.